# What is the main difference of getter and setter?

Tags: c#

I know this may be a silly question. I referred some articles. But, I am very interested to know the main difference for the following code,

```
using System;

namespace Business
{
    public class User
    {
        private int _id;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
using System;

namespace Business
{
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to know some brief details (any reference)...

Thanks

Comment: [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: Under the surface, the second example looks like the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example there is no difference.

However, *encapsulation* is an important aspect of object oriented programming. You typically do not want to have a wide open setter.

```
namespace Business
{
    public class User
    {
        private int _id;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { 
              if (value <= 0) 
                   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(value, "value", "Impossible value");

              _id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

By using a backing field you can also make sure that a value is specified in the constructor:

```
namespace Business
{
    public class User
    {
        private AccountState _state;

        public User()
        {
            _state = AccountState.Active;
        }

        public AccountState State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set { 
                 if (value == AccountState.Active && PasswordExpired)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Can not set active state when the password have expired");
                 _state = value; 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But in the constructor you can also set a auto-property, so whats the benfit there? The benefit is, that you can set the backing-field without a constructor IMO...

Answer (score 1):

There is no any difference for compiler, but there is differences in code.

You don't have a way to intercept `set` and `get` on auto-property, which you can do in normal case. If you ever worked with WPF, you will find there massive use of that "normal" properties.

```
public int Data  {
    get {}  
    set {
       //Do something ehere
    }
}
```

That means you can not debug them (auto-properties) or put break-point inside.

Comment: Actually you can put breakpoints into auto-implemented properties, but it's a PITA: `Debug` -> `New Breakpoint`->  `Break at function` and enter `YourClassName.get_YourPropertyName` into the `Function` textbox.

Answer (score 0):

After the compiler they are the same.

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

is just "syntax sugar".

This is called "[auto properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)" and is very usefull to reduce boiler plate code if you have "empty getter/setter" like in your example.

With auto-property you can no longer access the backing-field directly as it only exists after compilation, which can cause a very minor performance drawback IF the getter/setter is not inlined by the JIT.

Also at the moment there is no way to directly initialize an auto-property, but with the upcoming C# 6 you can do the following:

```
public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Auto-Implemented Properties (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)
were introduced in C# 3.0, prior to that you had to use your first version.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-implemented properties were introduced to facilitate and simplify this:

```
private int _id;

public int ID
{
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
}
```

into this:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

These two pieces of code are identical from the compiler point of view.

However, if you want to introduce any logic into your properties, then auto-implemented properties are NOT the way to go.

For example, if you want to verify that provided value of `id` must always be non-negative, you can implement this logic inside the setter like this:

```
private int _id;

public int ID
{
    get
    {
        return _id;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new BusinessException("You must provide a non-negative number for ID.");
        }

        _id = value;
    }
}
```

You cannot achieve this kind of flexibility with auto-implemented properties.